# How to get URL of OData service from SAP Gateway for connecting it with Web IDE Personal Edition?

Tags: odata, sap-web-ide, sap-gateway

I'm trying to connect SAP Web IDE Personal Edition" (local Web IDE) following this tutorial:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/2cf47f37e34c428c97a51057733c0394.html

But no connection happens. I guess the problem is in the host URL and the port. How can I get the URL? I tried using S4HANA URL but it didn't work. Also tried Fiori URL didn't work either.

How to get the Gateway URL and port?

Comment: Have you gone through the step _[Connect Remote Systems in SAP Web IDE Personal Edition](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/latest/en-US/2cf47f37e34c428c97a51057733c0394.html)_?

Comment: Yes, I did that is the link I was following  my issue is i can't find out what is the URL needed in that tutorial  how to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an on-premise system, then call /N/IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE, choose your service, click on Gateway Client, set the protocol to HTTPS and you'll see the full URL. If you don't then HTTPS isn't configured for your system --> call SMICM, Goto (from menu), Services and check the Host and Port columns in HTTP row. That's your host and port.